# Cloud Function requests showing undefined if used anywhere in the function, but if you just console log them, they come through fine

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

So this is a weird as hell issue I have been tinkering with for a bit and can't seem to figure out what the hell is going on here lol. I have this firebase function I am using to get some data from craigslist and return it back and in response. I am using request to send through some of the values I need to search for inside the cloud function.

```
exports.clSearch = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  console.log(request.body.keyword);
  console.log(request.body.city);

  let client = new craigslist.Client({
    city: "seattle",
  });

  options = {
    category: "vga",
    maxPrice: "500",
    minPrice: "100",
  };

  client
    .search(options, "xbox one")
    // eslint-disable-next-line promise/always-return
    .then((listings) => {
      // play with listings here...
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");

      response.send(listings);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
});
```

So this function above, when I run this, the console logs with the requests come through as the correct value and everything runs perfect as it should. Now look at this below:

```
exports.clSearch = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  console.log(request.body.keyword);
  console.log(request.body.city);

  let client = new craigslist.Client({
    city: request.body.city,
  });

  options = {
    category: "vga",
    maxPrice: "500",
    minPrice: "100",
  };

  client
    .search(options, request.body.keyword)
    // eslint-disable-next-line promise/always-return
    .then((listings) => {
      // play with listings here...
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");

      response.send(listings);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
});
```

Now basically all I am doing is just using those requests values, in the function not just logging them. However, when I do this, it causes the request to come through undefined for some reason in the console logs. Why would just using those request values further down in the function cause the requests to come through undefined?

Even if I just add

```
let keyword = request.body.keyword;
```

below the console logs, it causes the console logs above to come back as undefined. But if I only call the request.body.keyword / request.body.city via the console logs in the beginning, they come through completely fine. Only when I add them anywhere else in the function it causes everything to come back undefined. It literally makes no damn sense at all.

This is how I am sending the request to the function

```
  handleSearch = () => {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
      if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
      }
    });

    xhr.open(
      "POST",
      "https://*****.cloudfunctions.net/clSearch"
    );
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        keyword: "xbox",
        city: "orlando",
      })
    );
  };
```

Although I don't believe that is part of the issue I am going to show it anyways incase I am wrong.

Hopefully one of you super smart guys can figure this out or someone else has experienced this and can help lol.

Even if I do this

```
  let data = request;
  let rKey = data.body.keyword;
  let rCity = data.body.city;
  console.log(rCity);
  console.log(rKey);
```

those 2 console logs will come back as the proper value. But if I simply add rCity to

```
  let client = new craigslist.Client({
    city: rCity,
  });
```

then the two console logs show the value of rCity and rKey as undefined, even tho they logged the right value completely fine until I literally just try and use the value below. This makes no sense.

Comment: I notice that you're setting CORS headers as part of this cloud function's response. Can you clarify if this cloud function is handling both the POST request *and* the preflight CORS OPTIONS request? In the case of the latter, there would be no body. Maybe you are seeing the logs from the OPTIONS request. Can you confirm that whenever the logs show `undefined`, that the request method is in fact POST and not OPTIONS?

Comment: So basically this cloud function is taking the request, using it to get the value for city and keyword, then in the response it is returning the value of "listings" in the response. I have the cors headers set in the function since it is returning stuff in the response and I seemed to get errors without it. Plus, its working completely fine if I only console log it, but if I try to assign it to a variable or anything it makes it come back undefined on the console logs. Its weird.

Comment: Also its the request with the issue not the response, the data is sending fine back via the response totally fine, so I don't see how that could be the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by the node module node-craigslist, fuck that node module =D Simply using a new module solved that issue.